# Android - getTimeZone retornando data

Tags: android

Meu comando retorna no System apenas as horas, mas quando é postado no banco exibe as horas e a data.

Gostaria que retornasse apenas as horas, o que está de errado?

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-3:00"));
    Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    // you can get seconds by adding  "...:ss" to it
    date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-3:00"));
  final  String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

            Hours = localTime;


  System.out.println(localTime);
```

Saída:

> I/System.out: 09:54
>
> Post no banco ..

```
  postDataParams.put("hora_anun", Hours);
```

Comment: Você está gravando no banco data e hora ou somente hora?

Comment: No banco a coluna era apenas pra salvar as horas ,como no system ...Mas ele salva dessa forma "2017-06-30 09:54:00"

Comment: Não estou vendo o momento em que está salvando no banco. Tem certeza que está salvando a variável correta?! Não tem como reproduzir aqui.